# Is it possible to align MUI Snackbar relative to its parent div, rather than to relative to the entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a combination of Material UI's Snackbar & Alert components to display Success or Error messages following a database Post action.  Standard Material UI allows positioning of that message relative to the page using the `anchorOrigin` prop, which I have used to align the message centrally at the bottom of the page in the following code:

```
<Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={handleClose}         
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'bottom',
        horizontal: 'center',
    }}>

    <Alert
        severity={severity}
        variant="filled"
        sx={{ width: '100%' }}
        >
        {message}
    </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Rather than aligning to the overall page though, I would like to align the alert centrally relative to the parent div which contains the code which triggers the message.  Is there a way to do this?  I was looking at Material UI's custom `sx` prop to see if there was a way this could be used in my scenario, but couldn't see anything helpful.

Comment: What do you want to happen when user scrolls? To move the snack bar with the scrolled screen, or should it stay at it's fixed position like the MUI default behavior?

Comment: @Hamed Siaban The div that I want it in doesn;t have horizontal scroll.  It does resize depending on the users screen resolution - in that case the snackbar should remain central in the resized div.

The scenario is that I have a menu on the left of the page taking up perhaps 15% of the screen horizontally, and a data submission form on the right side (in a div) taking up the remaining 85% of the screen.  I want the snackbar to be positioned centrally within the right div under the data submission form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SnackBar's default position attribute is `fixed`.

> An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

We need to change that to `absolute`.

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

So we also need to make a parent positioned div for our snack bar to work as we expect. An example of positioned div can be a `position: relative` div.

```
<Box //This would be your resized div on the right side of page
  sx={{
    width: "500px",
    height: "500px",
    position: "relative",
  }}
>
  <Snackbar
    open={true}
    autoHideDuration={5000}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "center",
    }}
    sx={{ position: "absolute" }}
  >
    <Alert severity={"success"} variant="filled" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      {"message"}
    </Alert>
  </Snackbar>
</Box>
```

To learn more about positions [read this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your solution and the explanation, it's all working now

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this by setting the sx value for `top` and bottom to be more or less based on the anchorOrigin.vertical setting.

```
<Snackbar
  open={open}
  message={message}
  autoHideDuration={autoHideDurationDefault}
  onClick={onClick}
  onClose={onClick}
  anchorOrigin={anchorOrigin}
  // move further from top/bottom of the screen
  sx={anchorOrigin.vertical === "top" ? { top: "60px" } : { bottom: "60px" }}
>
  <Alert onClose={onClick} severity={severity} variant="filled">
    <Typography>{message}</Typography>
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.